# IBM DB2 Load failure to IBM DB2 Z/Os

Tags: db2, db2-zos

```
Connect to server user myuser using mypass;
LOAD CLIENT from "Text_File.TXT" OF DEL 
MODIFIED BY CHARDEL0x22 coldel0x09 KEEPBLANKS USEDEFAULTS  
TIMESTAMPFORMAT="YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.UUUUUUUUU" MESSAGES "Log_Text_File.TXT" 
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.Table NONRECOVERABLE;
```

This is my current command above, the single text file generated is below:

```
"int"   "AND 8 / 2010.  
"   "int"   "int"   "string"    "2014-03-12 14:52:29"   "name"  "int"
```

The error I'm getting is:

> SQL3116W  The field value in row "F8-8245" and column "6" is missing, but the 
>   target column is not nullable.
>
> SQL3185W  The previous error occurred while processing data from row "F8-8245" 
>   of the input file.

I'm using a text qualifier of "

It's a tab delimited file.

I'm not sure why the file is failing as the 6th column is filled.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not appear to have any relationship to sql server - so why is it tagged?

Comment: Your `TIMESTAMPFORMAT` specifies fractional seconds, while the input data don't have them; this might be the problem.

Comment: Are you sure your target is Db2 for z?

Comment: @mustaccio Yes I am sure the target is IBM DB2 z/OS
The source for column 6 is a  "datetime" column and the target is "Timestamp"

Comment: The reason sqlserver is tagged is because the source db is sqlserver and destination is ibm db2 z/os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input data file can contain a newline character inside a character-string value , then add DELPRIORITYCHAR to the modified-by list like this:

`MODIFIED BY CHARDEL0x22 coldel0x09 delprioritychar`

then retry and check the output. Remember to erase your message file before each load(or archive) so you only see fresh messages.